# How to Save Only selected checkbox id's in Datatable back to the Controller in an Array

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I have lookuup table in a database that contaions reasons with three columns namely 
Id , isSelected ,description , I used ajax to list them in a datatable as a checkbox list  , now i want to update the table via json with only the selected checkboxes for the reasons choosen from my Jsp page , I vae since tried many solutions but instead i only be able to save all the reasons from the list of checkboxes  even if some are not selected

here is a sample of my code below

```
var reasons = [];       
            var $tr = $("#recommReasonsTbt tr");

            $tr.each(function(){
            $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
            if(index !== -1){
            var id = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("name");
           // var isSelectedd = ($(id).find(':checked'));
           // alert("selectedd id  " + isSelectedd);
            var checkedRows = $(id).find("input:checked").parent().parent();
            alert("selectedd id  " + checkedRows);
            var total = checkedRows.length;
            alert("selectedd id  " + total);
            for(i = 0; i < total; i++){
            var row = $(checkedRows[i]).children();
            alert("row id  " + total);
            var tmpInfo = [];
            tmpInfo["id"]= row[0].innerHTML;
            tmpInfo["isSelected"]= row[1].innerHTML;
            tmpInfo["description"]= row[2].innerHTML;
            reasons.push(tmpInfo);
              }
            }
            else{   
                         reasons.push($(this).text());
                    }
            })
            });
```

all the reason are selected

Comment: have tried also the code below to no avail    var cols = [];
     $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
      if(index == 0){
       var id = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("name");
       alert("Attributes  " + id );
       cols.push(id);  
       var isSelected  = $(id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
       alert("selected ones  " + isSelected  );
       if(isSelected !== -1){
       alert("selected ones  " +  isSelected );
       cols.push(isSelected); 
       }

Comment: Please add code to your question by editing it.